# Toolbar and Databinding

Tags: android, data-binding

I'm trying to use Toolbar with the Databinding first time, but Toolbar is not seen in Databinding, probably. I want to pass data from the editText to the viewModel but the variable in viewmodel is still null. 
What could be wrong?

activity_main:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<data>

    <variable
        name="mainViewModel"
        type="com.example.daniellachacz.weatherapp2.viewmodel.MainViewModel">
    </variable>

</data>

<RelativeLayout
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".view.MainActivity">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:background="@color/design_default_color_primary_dark"
    android:theme="@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/colorWhite">

    <EditText
        android:text="@={mainViewModel.city}"
        android:id="@+id/city_edit_text"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:hint="Search location"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorGrey"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_below="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_marginTop="55dp">
</FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

</layout>
```

Activity:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ActivityMainBinding activityMainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
    final MainViewModel mainViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel.class);
    activityMainBinding.setMainViewModel(mainViewModel);

    androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar myToolbar = findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(activityMainBinding.myToolbar);

}
```

Comment: it would be helpful to see code of the `MainViewModel` as well. Is your `city` variable a `ObservableField<String>` or `LiveData<String>`? You need to have that for 2way data binding (`@=`).

Comment: I resolved problem. I didn't set setHasOptionsMenu(true); in fragment where I need edit text.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think this should have anything to do with 2way databinding variable being null, but if you say so :)

Comment: I set toolbar in main Activity, but this activity is only base for two fragments (layout with bottom navigation bar) and this is why data binding didn't see edit text.
It worked just in activity, but app starts on fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to remove `=` from `@={mainViewModel.city}` just **@{mainViewModel.city}**

Comment: Yes, still same.